# PyPI - allow importing a module using a different name

Tags: python, pip, python-import, pypi, python-packaging

I recently created a simple python package / library and uploaded it to ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/dcode.py)). That's all fine - I can upload my project to pypi and download it again using pip, but I can't import it because it contains a full stop `.`
My package is called `dcode.py` (which obviously causes issues with importing), I'd like to be able to import it by just typing `import dcode` (without the `.py`). I've looked around for a solution but can't seem to find one - I'd like to be able to import it under an alias (`dcode`) instead of `dcode.py` (which obviously doesn't work).
Is there a way to do this? I'd assume there must be (for example, both the packages `discord.py` and `py-cord` can both just be imported using `import discord`. Does anyone know how to do this?

Just in case you need it, my `pyproject.toml` file looks like this:

```ini
[project]
name = "dcode.py"
version = "0.0.2"
authors = [
{ name = "Dylan Rogers", email = "opendylan@proton.me" },
]
description = "dcode - the Python package for everything"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=2.0"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "https://github.com/dylanopen/dcode.py"
"Bug Tracker" = "https://github.com/dylanopen/dcode.py/issues"
```

And my entire project is [on github](https://github.com/dylanopen/dcode.py).
Here is the [PyPI project](https://pypi.org/project/dcode-py)

I've tried importing `dcode.py`:

```py
import dcode.py
```

But I just get this error:

```
File "/run/media/dylan/Programming/dcode.py-test/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import dcode_py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dcode_py'
```

If it helps, I'm using Manjaro Linux (no idea why it would help though, I just need to know how to allow users to import `dcode.py` by typing `import dcode`, like they import `discord.py` as `discord`)

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Any help is appreciated, thanks, if you need more clarification, please ask! (This is my new account by the way)

Comment: why import dcode.py not import dcode

Comment: I've looked into the `importlib` and `imp` modules, but I'd prefer to let users import normally if it's possible

Comment: @stunlocked I tried import dcode, but it doesn't work either. The dcode package was already taken on PyPI, so I used dcode.py instead.

Comment: you could create a folder dcode/py/ and move everything there, also create an empty dcode/py/__init__.py file so that it is considered a module. That way import dcode.py is similar to from dcode import py

Comment: @stunlocked Thanks, is there a way to package this for PyPI? I didn't use 'dcode' as it was taken - is there a way to set up this folder structure on an existing project?

Comment: The directory structure of your project seems "incorrect", or at the very least it breaks many best practices, and I am quite sure it is not actually what you want. I would not know where to start, there are many things to fix. I recommend you follow this tutorial, and pay particular attention to the directory structure: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/ -- Having a project named `dcode.py` with a dot is not an issue at all, what matters is the name of the import modules and import packages.

Comment: Did you choose a build back-end? It does not seem like you have. Do you want to use *setuptools* as build back-end or something else? You need a `[build-system]` section in your `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: I've used a Makefile as my backend build. How do you specify the import module / package name?

Comment: You should not push any `*.egg-info` directory into the source code repository. You should not have any `__init__.py` right at the root of the project's source code directory.

Comment: A Makefile is not a Python build-back-end. I recommend you read the tutorial carefully from top to bottom.

Comment: You should not push the `dist` directory containing the *sdist* and *wheel* artifacts into the source code repository.

Comment: You choose the names of the import modules and import packages by creating files and directories with those names. Names must be valid Python identifiers.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I'll have a look. I might just rename my library instead. My question was, do you know if it's possible to import a package using a different name than the package name. For example, you can import the 'discord.py' library as just 'discord', I wondered how to do that with my package.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but I really would recommend against it, it only brings confusion, and you seem to be struggling already, so my advice is to keep things simple.

Comment: I would suggest you use a `.gitignore` to stop some of the files being pushed to github. A good starting point is https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Python.gitignore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the recommended directory structure your project should have:

```
dcode.py/
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── src/
│   └── dcode/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── io/
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── file.py
└── tests/
```

Here `dcode` (as defined by `dcode.py/src/dcode`) is the name of the only top-level importable package. And it also contains a sub-package `dcode.io` (as defined by `dcode.py/src/dcode/io`).

The name of the actual distribution project as seen on *PyPI* and that gets *pip*-installed is defined in the package metadata, in the `pyproject.toml` file:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "dcode.py"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [
  { name = "Dylan Rogers", email = "opendylan@proton.me" },
]
description = "dcode - the Python package for everything"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.8"

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "https://github.com/dylanopen/dcode.py"
"Bug Tracker" = "https://github.com/dylanopen/dcode.py/issues"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]
```

Do not push the `dist` directory containing the built *sdist* and *wheel* distribution packages artifacts into the source code repository.

Do not push any `*.egg-info` directory into the source code repository.

Place all the actual Python code inside a `src` directory.

The name of the project can contain a dot such as `dcode.py`, although I would recommend against it.

The name of the actual top-level import packages and modules can be completely different than the name of the distribution project.

If you declare a *classifier* for the license in the package metadata in `pyproject.toml`, then it should match the actual license file in the source code repository (you had a *GNU GPL v3.0* license file but a *MIT* license classifier).

***References***:

- https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/
- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html
- https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/packaging.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't realise this - I sort of skipped some of the guide :)
I would upvote it but I don't have any reputation :/